# Contradicting iOS runtime constraint error

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am getting an unsatisfiable constraints error at runtime (iOS 8.3, XCode 6.3, iPad Air simulator), but the error itself is contradicting with the data that I observe in View Hierarchy debugger.

The runtime error:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96a8e30 V:[PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890(100)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b943fa00 V:[UIView:0x7fd7b943f7d0(80)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96ac9a0 V:|-(0)-[PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd7b943f7d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96ad3a0 PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890.bottom == UIView:0x7fd7b943f7d0.bottom>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96a8e30 V:[PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890(100)]>
```

In Visual Hierarchy debugger, I select the constraints listed above and view them in Object inspector. Here they are in order or appearance:

```
Address: 0x7fd7b96a8e30
First Item: PushDownView
Relation: Equal
Multiplier: 1
Constant: 100
Priority: 76

Address: 0x7fd7b943fa00
First Item: UIView
Relation: Equal
Multiplier: 1
Constant: 100
Priority: 76

Address: 0x7fd7b96ac9a0
First Item: PushDownView
Relation: Equal
Multiplier: 1
Constant: 0
Priority: 76

Address: 0x7fd7b96ad3a0
First Item: PushDownView
Relation: Equal
Multiplier: 1
Constant: 0
Priority: 76
```

Look at the constraint `0x7fd7b943fa00` - the error claims it's setting UIView's height to 80. But the Object inspector claims the constant is 100.

As far as I know, I set everything to be 100 in code (but I might be mistaken, so let's stick to facts here).

What am I missing here? Why the error's and the Visual Hierarchy inspector's values are different?

Comment: did you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO before adding constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I see the next problem on your constraints:

```
1. <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96a8e30 V:[PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890(100)]>
```

- you set 'height' to 100

```
2. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96ac9a0 V:|-(0)-[PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd7b943f7d0 )>",
```

- the following constraints tell us to 'pin' view to top of superview

```
3. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd7b96ad3a0 PushDownView:0x7fd7b96a8890.bottom == UIView:0x7fd7b943f7d0.bottom>"
```

- as you see, this constraint pins PushDownView to the bottom of UIView bottom.

We now have conflict between this 3 constraints - it causes when uiview tries to layout it subviews.

Remove height constraint or remove last constraint  - it depends upon what you want - if you want PushDownView to scale - remove first, if you need fixed height - remove third

Comment: Thanks for providing possible solutions to the constraints error, I appreciate it! Removing the height constraint from PushDownView does indeed remove the runtime error. But please read my question -- **I am asking about the conflict between the error and the data I am inspecting in the Visual Hierarchy debugger.** I thought I made that clear by writing it in the title as well as the actual question at the end of my post. Thanks! :)

Comment: ou, i've missed that ) did you check all the code for uiview's constraint changes? sounds like it set height equals to another view.. did you have another constarints?